Page reload due to Cookie Consent banner causing loss of inital taffic source in google analytics
Once user accepts cookie (onetrust) we are reloading the page (with window.location.reload()) to make sure everything works fine.
But this page reload is causing issue in google analytics as the page reload is causing the loss of initial traffic as a result all traffic is categorized as DIRECT.
The page reload should preserve initial traffic source.

You should not reload once you receive consent update. Usually you link your processes to the update of the consent. What processes require you to reload the page?
If you have to reload the page, you wil have to setup some cookie logic to remember the referral and push it to GA.

The page reload is needed due to some personalization dependencies so i cannot disable page reload, Can you give any script snippet for the cookie logic and sending to GA you are suggesting , Thanks! @Gengis
